# Hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW not detected in Ubuntu or PC

Tags: ros, ethernet, ros-groovy, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a newbie user for ROS. I am trying to run the Hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW LiDAR (with ethernet connection) using urg_node on Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS-Groovy.

When I run the following commands (in separate terminal windows)

```
roscore
rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"
```

I get the following error:

```
[FATAL] [1368644464.256278611]: Could not open network Hokuyo:
192.168.0.10:10940
could not open ethernet port.
```

Sadly, I also cannot get the tools issued by the manufacturer to detect the LiDAR when I try to connect in a Windows environment.

For both these situations, the laser scanner is switched on and connected when this happens. Also, the LEDs are lit steady after blinking for a few seconds on connection.

Can someone please provide me suggestions about what might be going on? Our lab spent a lot of money buying this equipment and I would like that to be put to good use!

Thanks in advance :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62830/hokuyo-utm-30lx-ew-not-detected-in-ubuntu-or-pc/) by [redarean](https://answers.ros.org/users/4903/redarean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-05-20**:
You are correct, the urg_node will not work if there is no connectivity to the laser.  Setting the IP address of the computer to match that of the laser should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I heard back from the manufacturer's technical support just now and his troubleshooting tip resolved the problem. Apparently, it was an IP mismatch with my corporate network computer all along! I am pasting his reply below so that others may benefit from this.

Moderators, please close this question (I do not have sufficient reputation to do so)

Thanks!

---

From: Sup PREMVUTI (Kirinson, Inc.) []
Sent: Wednesday, May 15, 2013 3:49 PM
Subject: RE: Cannot connect to the Hokuyo UTM-30LX-EW

Hi,

Please try the following steps.

(1) Use a Windows PC or Laptop and use its Ethernet port directly.
(2) Set the property of your Ethernet port TCP/IP4 to the following. (Do not select ‘Obtain an IP address automatically’)

```
   IP Address 192.168.0.15
   Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway 192.168.0.1
```

The laser scanner and the PC have to be on the same net, e.g. 192.168.0.XX. For this step, we put the PC on 192.168.0.15. The default IP address of the laser scanner is 192.168.0.10 and port number is 10940.

(3) Connect the laser scanner to the Ethernet port of the PC.

(4) Run URG Benri.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks,

Sup

---

---

Originally posted by [redarean](https://answers.ros.org/users/4903/redarean/) with karma: 81 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2